# closed solution for non linear system

Tags: dynamical-systems, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

For linear systems of the form $Ax = \dot x$, one can find a close solution of the form:
$
\dot x(t) = e^{At} x(0)
$

Is there a way to show that a nonlinear solution of the form, $A(x) x = \dot x$ has no closed-form solution? You could have a solution in small time steps, for example, $\dot (x+ \tau) = e^{A(x) \tau} x(t)$. But given that $A(x)$ is dependent on x, I guess it is possible to have a closed solution because, at each time step, the x vector needs to be accounted for in A.
Is there a way to formally show that?

The reason I ask is people keep seeking this closed for solution for the nonlinear system, and it seems to me impossible, am I wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It could be interesting you give an example for $A(x)$

Comment: No, the first claim is not true as special cases most likely exist. // A solution in terms of the matrix exponential does already not exist in general for time-variable $A=A(t)$. // Of course one may apply the Euler method or the exponential Euler method, but that only gives first-order approximations to a solution.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for your answer. But how can I prove that the matrix exponential does already not exist in general for time-variable A = A(t)?

Comment: The matrix exponential as operation does exist, it just has no relation to the solution in similarity to the scalar case. The exception is the special case that all matrices for all parameters commute. In some interesting cases one can express the solution or a factor of it as matrix exponential, but then the exponent has a non-trivial relation to the system matrix of the ODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is there a way to show that a nonlinear system has no closed-form solution?"
Yes, there is!

The existence of a "closed-form" solution is constrained to an resonance condition. More precisely:

**Corollary:** If the eigenvalues of $f(x)$ around a fixed point $x_*$, where the Jacobian matrix is semi-simple, are $\Bbb N$-independent, then there is no formal first integral.

This is Corollary 5.2 from Goriely's [Integrability and Nonintegrability of Dynamical Systems](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/3846).

Comment: Thanks! Can you just let me know what is ℕ
-independent? I took a look at the book, but I am not that familiar with nonlinear dynamics.

Comment: A set of numbers $a_1,a_2,...,a_k$ is $\Bbb N$-independent if there's no solution (in $\Bbb N$) to $n_1a_1+n_2a_2+...+n_ka_k=0$ other than $n_1=n_2=...=n_k=0$. Also consider accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I accepted the answer. In my case, at the equilibrium point, my system is diagonal, and the eigenvalues are all equal except the last diagonal element, which is zero! So the set will be $n_1 \lambda + n_2 \lambda + \cdots + n_n \cdot 0  = 0$, which has only $n_1 =n_2 = ...=n_n = 0$. So it is an N-independent set. Right?

Comment: The last term can be any number. But your matrix is not semi-simple.

Comment: Isn't semi-simple just the fact that the matrix can be written through the sum of the other two square matrices?
I have another question, if I may. In the book, the author states rational integral and formal integral. Can you walk me trough the difference?

Comment: Sorry.. I might not have explained right. My system is $\dot x = (A + f(x)) x$. A is a diagonal matrix, but the nonlinear matrix f(x) is not. However, in the equilibria point, f(x) turns out to become diagonal, but just in the $x^{*} point$. My goal is to check if there is any closed form solution to this non linear system.

Comment: These definitions (rational and formal first integrals) are in the first chapter and I strong suggest you to read it. About the matrix note that the result uses the jacobian .